# compare and delete duplicate column from 2 csv files with delimeter in Unix

Tags: csv, unix, text, duplicates, text-processing

Is that possible to find and remove duplicate not enire row, but only "row which contains duplicate column"?

1.csv contains

```
,364-52-2326,,,,,,,
```

2.csv contains

```
1958-12-22T00:00:00,364-52-2326,KONZEN,"ROBERT,JR.",M,85308,NULL,NULL,NULL
1945-04-03T00:00:00,516-34-9103,BLUMFIELD,DONALD,M,85254,NULL,NULL,NULL
1978-11-22T00:00:00,364-52-2326,THOMAS,COLLEEN,F,85032,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

The output result needs to be:

```
1945-04-03T00:00:00,516-34-9103,BLUMFIELD,DONALD,M,85254,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

so:

a) removing lines with duplicate column from 2.csv (in my example 364-52-2326)

b) comparing 1.csv with 2.csv and removing duplicates in 2.csv

Comment: Your example input might not be the best choice because it contains very few lines (assuming your real input files are bigger) and it is not clear if all input corresponds to the special case of your example. If it is possible that a "duplicate" exists in `2.csv` which does not match the data in `1.csv` you should also add such an example.

Comment: ... Otherwise, duplicates doesn't seem to describe your issue. You have only deleted rcords in file2 for records listed in file1. ALSO, S.O. isn't a free code writing service, we'll help you fix your best attempt at solving your problem. Please user proper formatting for code, data, sample output, error messages (if you get them) Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.